# How to add items dynamically to recyclerview?

Tags: android, json, textview, android-recyclerview

I want to add items dynamically to recyclerview.Based on the current json response i have created recyclerview.But I want to make it dynamic,Coz I dont know in future there might be many items that has to be shown in recyclerview.There is no fixed item size.How can I solve this..Below is my code.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

public class LeadRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private static ArrayList leadLists;

```
public LeadRVAdapter(List<Lead> leadLists, FragmentNavigation fragmentNavigation) {
    this.leadLists = (ArrayList<Lead>) leadLists;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View listItem= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lead_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Lead myListData = leadLists.get(position);
    holder.firstname.setText(myListData.getFirstname());
    holder.leadno.setText(myListData.getLeadNo());
    holder.leadstatus.setText(myListData.getLeadstatus());
    holder.modTime.setText(myListData.getModifiedtime());
    holder.parent1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("TYPE", myListData.getLeadNo());
```

//pass data to detail activity

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Lead No", leadLists.get(position).getFirstname());
                intent.putExtra("First Name", leadLists.get(position).getFirstname());
                intent.putExtra("Lead Status", leadLists.get(position).getLeadstatus());
                intent.putExtra("Modified Time", leadLists.get(position).getModifiedtime());
                intent.putExtra("Last Name", leadLists.get(position).getLastname());
                intent.putExtra("Mobile No", leadLists.get(position).getMobile());
                intent.putExtra("Company", leadLists.get(position).getCompany());
                intent.putExtra("Designation", leadLists.get(position).getDesignation());


                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);


            }
    );

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return leadLists.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView leadstatus,firstname,modTime,leadno,lastname,mobile,company,designation;
    public View parent1;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        firstname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_firstName);
        leadno=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_leadno);
        leadstatus=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_leadStatus);
        modTime=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_modifiedtime);
        lastname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_lastname);
        parent1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent1);
        mobile=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_mobile);
        company=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_company);
        designation=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_designation);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add new lead to your leadLists and call adapter's method  notifyDataSetChanged() . Like this:

```
leadLists.add(new Lead())


leadRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Where I should add this code?And what i should remove?

Comment: First recyclerview set the adapter. Then add this code to line where json response comes from. You can change this code for you.